# AFNetworking issue with JSONRequest

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking to get a JSON from a server.
My problem is that in case the session is expired the server is replying with a string "NOSESSION".

This is my code:

```
[AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request


                                  success: ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON){


                                      NSArray *jsonArray =[JSON valueForKey:@"posts"];

                                        //DOING SOMETHING WITH jsonArray
                                        // in case that the response is NOSESSION do something                                        



                                  }

                                  failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON){




                                       }];

[operation start];
```

My problem here is that this is request is failing because the response is not string.
The error message:

```
Failed Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.)
```

Is there any way to know the response string? (I dont mind to catch it in failure I just want to know when the session is expired)

Answer (score 0):

You could check the statusCode of your NSHTTPURLResponse. When your server encounters such an error, he typically returns a statusCode.

Example: 
403: forbidden
404: page not found
500: internal server error.

You could check that the HTTP statusCode is between 200 & 400. ==> no errors

```
if(response.statusCode < 400 && response.statusCode > 200) {
    // do normal stuff 
} else {
    // handle error
}
```

You can find more info on HTTP statusCodes here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: My problem is not with error code. My problem is that I want to know what the server respond. Maybe the database is down. How I will understand if the database is down or the user has expired session/